# Trying to do my first loop in SQL but error in variable declaration

Tags: loops, hana, sapb1

First, just to say I'm new here and new to programming, so I've never used sql in sap.

I'm trying to learn how to create a query in which I'm trying to loop a table. Here is an abbreviated version of the table:

OALI

```
OrigItem AltItem
1        2
2        3
4        5
5        6
```

I want to retrieve the last AltItem in the chain, so 1 would give 3 and 4 would be 6.

```
OrigItem AltItem FinalItem
1        2       3
2        3       3
4        5       6
5        6       6
```

I'm sure this is simple, but I get an erro on the declaration of the variable.

BTW, if you can help me out with a good place to learn SQL for SAP, that you be great.

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far, what code did you use and what was the exact error message? Please review the guidelines on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to provide a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This could lead to one SELECT or subSELECT per table row if it contains one big chain. That cloud take several days. If the table has less than 2 _billion_ rows, you are probably better off with selecting every line to an internal table.

Comment: While you def. should try and make your scenario more clear, it seems you're looking for a graph/hierarchy query to find the last "AltItem" for any chain of "OrigItem" -> "AltItem". That's a classic hierarchy query, and depending on your actual scenario, SAP HANA provides multiple options to model those. Look out for "Hierarchy" in the modelling guide.

Comment: First of all, I apologise for not providing any example of my work, but since I'm new to programming, and I've moved into programming out of need, I pretty sure my example will not make much sense.

Comment: First of all, I apologise for not providing any example of my work, but since I'm new to programming, and to the site, and I've moved into programming out of need, I pretty sure my example will not make much sense, but here it goes @vwegert:
DECLARE i int =0; SELECT T0."OrigItem", T0."AltItem", WHILE i<>NULL DO SELECT T0."OrigItem", T0."AltItem"  FROM OALI T0 WHERE i=T0."OrigItem"; i=T0."AltItem" END WHILE  FROM OALI T0

Comment: @András I have very little understand of programming, but since the table is small, less the 10K rows, I though it wouldn't have an impact on the system every time I run the query

Comment: OALI = SAP B1 = I'm out. And I'm not sure whether B1 runs on HANA, so the tag possibly isn't correct either.

Comment: @vwegert thank you, I was told that que version we have of B1 (9.2) runs HANA, so I'm assuming that this is true

Comment: Are you using SQL, or HANA? They're very different things. Your question says SQL but your tags say HANA. SAP B1 runs on either SQL or HANA, it depends on your individual installation (e.g. we're running 9.1 on SQL 2012).

Comment: @ZacFaragher HANA 9.1

Answer (score 0):

You can't do a `WHILE` statement within a `SELECT` statement, it just won't work.

The way you would go about this is different depending on what exactly you're trying to achieve.

You could use a cursor to get a result set that you can iterate over, or store your temporary results to a #Temp_Table or @Table_Variable and delete them one by one as you complete the iteration.

All this being said, any iterative procedure in SQL will be much slower than a Set Based query, so see if you can avoid loops of any kind if possible.

One thing you could look at is nested `SELECT` statements, like so:

```
SELECT OrigItem, AltItem,
    (SELECT COUNT(AltItem)
         FROM OALI T1
         WHERE T0.OrigItem = T1.OrigItem) as 'AltItem Count'
FROM OALI T0
```